# Iterating through PySpark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 large dataframes:

**df_1**

- My Store Names
- 70k+ rows
- 9 columns

**df_2**

- Google Maps Store Names
- 30k rows
- 14 columns

And I want to iterate through `df_1` to perform some text similarity operations (e.g. distance) with the names in `df_2`, if a match is found, the name in my `df_1` gets flagged as found.

There is a common column between the 2 dataframes which is `city`, it could be used for a join operation but the resulting dataframe would be too large (millions of rows).

Is there an efficient way achieve my goal while utilizing the parallelism of spark?

I tried collecting `df_2` then broadcasting it, and using it with the function `withColumn()` that gets applied to `df_1`, but the `collect()` causes some memory issues, and the `broadcast()` takes forever.

Comment: It'd be good if you can share your dataframes' structure as well, so we can get a better understanding of the scenario.

Comment: Do you have some location fields? Maybe you could build clusters and perform matching inside clusters. It significantly decreases the size of the problem in smaller chunks. Unfortunately you address the matching problem which is O(n^2). I suggest you to look for Blocking strategies (divide and conquer). I hope the slang terms help you to find resources :)

Comment: having a view into your sample data will help, but you can definitely use 'withColumn' to create a flag column using 'when' function to check availability from DF2 in DF1